# Historical distribution of the Android platform versions

Tags: android, version

I am interested in the distribution of the Android platform versions and I thus enjoy the www page http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html. I would like to get hold of historical distribution data. Does anyone know where to find complete data-series stretching from December 2009?

Comment: This doesn't belong here. Voted to move it to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I agree it's off topic on SO. I'd suggest asking this on the [android-platform](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-platform) discussion group.

Comment: I'd would like to find this data also.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so I was bored and made [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TA4mW6csdLovDuIaQCelc58HPSOzo5CfLUjZvxtJ1MQ/pubchart?oid=2024187015&format=interactive) motion chart using Google Spreadsheets. I used http://www.droid-life.com/tag/distribution/ as a reference for the past distributions.

In the upper right hand corner, you can select the bar graph; on the x-axis, you can select "Order: Alphabetical".
The data goes back to 2012. Unfortunately I couldn't find data from 2009. I will update the graph every month.

**EDIT**: The Motion Chart in Google Spreadsheets is now deprecated. Here is a link to the spreadsheet containing all the data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TA4mW6csdLovDuIaQCelc58HPSOzo5CfLUjZvxtJ1MQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for this! +1 for the chart and including the source.

Comment: Just to complete your answer: http://www.bidouille.org/misc/androidcharts

Answer (score 1):

I'm also interested into gathering this data. The only place I could find this is with [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

You can there visit the previous data. I will try to get it when I get some time and will report back (unless someone wants to do it first :) )

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this answer is WAY past the original post, but for those who come across this question, this information is available on Wikipedia [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Android_historical_version_distribution.png).

Comment: Looks like this only goes up to 2/4/2014.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chart on wikipedia that is updated regularly. It will give a view of the distribution of various android releases over time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history